# The given key was not present in the dictionary exception

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a websocket server writed in c#C#. When i'm handling a packet from client in the server I get the error:

`The given key ´4´ was not present in the dictionary.`

This key exist. Other keys doesn't has this problem. The code pass the if statement.

```
string rawdata = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decoded);
string[] msgdata = rawdata.Split("--");

int funcId = int.Parse(msgdata[0]);

if (Server.packetHandlersWS.ContainsKey(funcId)) {
    Server.packetHandlersWS[funcId](id, msgdata);
}
```

I tried cleanup on my project, i've tried delet the .pdb files in the project and rebuild. None of this fixes the problem.

Comment: well, what type is `packetHandlersWS`? if this container is shared between concurrent requests, the type *really really* matters

Comment: (note: `TryGetValue` is probably useful here, too, but that is a side topic)

Comment: my delegate and the dictionary declaration:


`public delegate void PacketHandlerWS(int _fromClient, string[] _pkgData);

public static Dictionary<int, PacketHandlerWS> packetHandlersWS;` 

and the assignment of the method that i'm trying access:


`public static void DisconnectRequest(int _fromClient, string[] _data)`

Comment: I tried change to ´TryGetValue´ and use ´Invoke´ to call methods, but the error persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `packetHandlersWS` is `Dictionary<,>` (from comments), there's a very good chance that you've corrupted the internal state, because you aren't doing any synchronization - and `Dictionary<,>` is **not** thread-safe. If this is the case, there's a very real chance that switching to `ConcurrentDictionary<,>` will fix this (note: you should still use `TryGetValue` with `ConcurrentDictionary<,>`, to avoid another race condition).